# Programming (Computer Algebra System) for Paired Suborbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, math-software, python, gap

The orbits of $G \leq Sym(\Omega)$ on $\Omega × \Omega$ are called the orbitals of $G$
on $\Omega$.

For each orbital $\Delta$ there is a paired orbital denoted $\Delta'$, where
$(y, x) \in \Delta'$ if and only if $(x, y) \in \Delta$.

For each orbital $\Delta$ of $G$ and each $x \in \Omega$  we define $\Delta(x) = \{y \in  \Omega |(x, y) \in \Delta\}$. Such sets are exactly the suborbits of point stabilizer $G_x$.

If $\Delta$ and $\Delta'$ are paired orbitals, then $\Delta(x)$ and $\Delta'(x)$ are called paired suborbits.

A suborbit $\Delta(x)$  is called self-paired if $\Delta(x)=\Delta'(x)$.

MAIN QUESTION

Is there any math software (computer algebra system) that shows output as graph or computes orbital and paired orbital  $\Delta$,  $\Delta'$,  $\Delta(x)$, $\Delta'(x)$ (for symmetric group input)? Can anyone provide a program for these in any language? Programming language Python, Computer Algebra System GAP are preferable.

SUPPLEMENTARY QUESTION

Can any one demonstrate $\Delta(x)$ and $\Delta'(x)$ for a permutation group acting on a domain? Please provide example with sufficient large set to demonstrate definitions.

Comment: Your orbital $\Delta=\{(x,y),(x,z),(y,z)\}$ isn't possible unless $x=y=z$: $(x,y),(y,z)\in\Delta$ so there is some $g\in G$ so that $xg=y$ and $yg=z$.  Then $(y,z)g=(z,*)\in \Delta$, so either $z=x$ or $z=y$.  In either case, either $(x,z)$ or $(y,z)$ in $\Delta$ is part of the diagonal, so $x=y=z$ and so $\Delta=\Delta'$ and $\Delta(x)=\Delta'(x)=\{x\}$.

Comment: Anyway, the usual action of $S_n$ on $[n]$ is primitive, so I don't know what you want from "symmetric group acting on a domain".  You want imprimitive actions to have any non-self-paired orbitals, e.g., subgroups of $S_m\wr S_n$.

Comment: @user10354138 that is artificial example, If I have a real example I wouldn't post the question, also I wanted to mean permutation group, plz give any example that clearly demonstrates the definitions

Comment: Try the action of $\langle (12)\rangle\times\langle (34)\rangle\subseteq S_4$ on the sixteen elements of $\{1,2,3,4\}\times\{1,2,3,4\}$ working out the six orbitals, and then the twenty-four $\Delta(x)$. You'll see that there are four self-paired orbitals each of size 2, and two paired orbitals each of size 4.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Try the action of $\langle (12)\rangle\times\langle (34)\rangle\subseteq S_4$ on the sixteen elements of $\{1,2,3,4\}\times\{1,2,3,4\}$: I found 4 -  

$$\{1,2,3,4\}\times\{1,2,3,4\}$$

$$\{2,1,3,4\}\times\{1,2,3,4\}$$

$$\{1,2,3,4\}\times\{1,2,4,3\}$$ 

$$\{2,1,3,4\}\times\{1,2,4,3\}$$, plz point out my mistake(s), thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you are saying - you've written down the same set four times. Hint: One orbital is $\{(1,3), (2,3), (1,4), (2,4)\}$. Another is $\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician well I have changed the order but I do see the problem, anyway, I  am going to declare 50 bounty points in 16 hours, please consider posting a full answer, thanks.

Comment: I think you are confused about notation, and that may be the root of your problem. As I said, each of the sets you have written down is exactly the whole set of sixteen pairs. The orbitals are proper subsets of this and I suggest you write down explicity where each of the four elements of $G$ sends each pair $(a,b)$ ($a,b\in\{1,2,3,4\}$). Then you'll have the orbitals. Now calculate the stabiliser $G_1$ (it has order 2). Then calculate the orbits of $G_1$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ Now calculate for each orbital $\Delta$ the sets $\Delta(1)$. You'll learn more this way than just reading my calculations.

Comment: @ancientmathematician $V_4 = \{1,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\} < S_4$. From all possible 16 pairs $(a,b)$, where $a, b \in \Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$, I can find:

$(1,3)^{(12)(34)}=(2,4)$

$(1,2)^{(13)(24)}=(3,4)$

$(1,2)^{(14)(23)}=(4,3)$

, identity element does not move any pair, so, $\Delta=\{ (2,4), (3,4), (4,3)\}$ and $\Delta'= \{ (3,4), (4,3)\}$ ?

Comment: $V_4$ is not the group I suggested you look at- although isomorphic the actions of $V_4$ and $S_2\times S_2$ are different.  But your calculations are astray for it: (i) you have an orbital of size 3, and 3 does not divide $|V_4|$ (ii) you have $\Delta$ and $\Delta'$ distinct but overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

Just so that there is an answer for the main question (even if ignoring the supplemental question) for readers in the future:

Orbitals are orbits on pairs. E.g. for some group of degree 8:

```
gap> pairs:=Tuples([1..8],2);;
gap> Length(pairs); # 8^2
64
gap> g:=TransitiveGroup(8,20);; # just some group
gap> orb:=List(Orbits(g,pairs,OnTuples),Set);
[ [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 3, 3 ], [ 4, 4 ], [ 5, 5 ], [ 6, 6 ], [ 7, 7 ],
      [ 8, 8 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 6 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 2, 7 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 4, 1 ],
      [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 2 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 6, 3 ], [ 6, 7 ], [ 7, 4 ], [ 7, 8 ],
      [ 8, 1 ], [ 8, 5 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 1, 7 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 2, 8 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 4, 2 ],
      [ 4, 6 ], [ 5, 3 ], [ 5, 7 ], [ 6, 4 ], [ 6, 8 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 7, 5 ],
      [ 8, 2 ], [ 8, 6 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 1, 8 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 4, 3 ],
      [ 4, 7 ], [ 5, 4 ], [ 5, 8 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 6, 5 ], [ 7, 2 ], [ 7, 6 ],
      [ 8, 3 ], [ 8, 7 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 5 ], [ 2, 6 ], [ 3, 7 ], [ 4, 8 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 6, 2 ], [ 7, 3 ],
      [ 8, 4 ] ] ]
```

Now look at the sets of the reversed tuples and the pairing correspondence:

```
gap> opair:=List(orb,x->Set(List(x,Reversed)));;
gap> List(opair,x->Position(orb,x));
[ 1, 4, 3, 2, 5 ]
```

So orbit number  1 is self-paired, while number  2 is paired with number 4 and 3 with 5.

The associated suborbits (I pick $x=1$) are the numbers paired with $1$:

```
gap> x:=1;subo:=List(orb,o->Filtered(o,y->y[1]=x));
1
[ [ [ 1, 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 6 ] ], [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 1, 7 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 1, 8 ] ], [ [ 1, 5 ] ] ]
gap> subo:=List(subo,x->Set(List(x,y->y[2])));
[ [ 1 ], [ 2, 6 ], [ 3, 7 ], [ 4, 8 ], [ 5 ] ]
```

So e.g. the suborbit $\{2,6\}$ is paired with $\{4,8\}$, while $\{1\}$ is self-paired.

Comment: The last example calculates the suborbits $\Delta(1)$, associated to the orbitals in teh same oreder (and thus paired in the same way).

Comment: Yes I got that,  but if you use notations it would be much helpful, thanks.